# Python list operation

Tags: python, list, operation

I have two lists  **ListA**  and  **ListB**  as follow:

```
ListA=['1','1','2','2','2','3','4','4','5','5','5','5']
ListB=['1','5']
```

I am trying to come up with **List C** which has the same length as **List A** but replace the numbers in the **List A** with **'X'** if the number is in the **List B**.The result i am expecting:

```
ListC=['X','X','2','2','2','3','4','4','X','X','X','X']
```

FYI, length of **ListB** will always less than the length of **ListA** and  **ListB** will not hold any numbers that is not in  **List A**.

I have tried like this:

```
ListA=['1','1','2','2','2','3','4','4','5','5','5','5']
ListB=['1','5']
ListC=[]
for items in ListB:
    for a in ListA:
        if items==a:
            ListC.append('X')
        else:
            ListC.append(a)
```

obviously this will create a List that has (length of listB X lenght A) rather than just just the length of list A. Is there any built in function that does this operation? Could anyone give me a clue how to do it?

Comment: I reckon you would be better off with a dictionary of replacements, like `{1=>X, 5=>O}` and then simply `newList=[dct.get(x,x) for x in oldList]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
[i if i not in ListB else 'X' for i in ListA]
```

To fix your current code, use `in` to check to see if the item is in `ListB`:

```
for item in ListA:
    if item in ListB:
        ListC.append('X')
    else:
        ListC.append(item)
```

Comment: Not trying to be pesky.. let's say if we have 1 more list, ListD=['O','X'] which has the same length as ListB. Assuming all the conditions on question is still applied but instead of replacing with 'X' for the match item, can we replace the match item in List A with items in List C? Which means we are still comparing List A and B but if first item of B is in A, then replace the matched item of A with first item of C. example( ListD=['O','O','2','2','2','3','4','4','X','X','X','X'])

Comment: nvm i managed to get it working by using "index" thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Any time you are doing membership tests over and over on the same `list`, it's a good idea to create a `set`. Although it takes some time to construct the `set` the individual lookups can be much faster

```
SetB = set(ListB)
[i if i not in SetB else 'X' for i in ListA]
```

Comment: Ouh, that's very clever! Doesn't Python do it internally somehow without us knowing it ? I know Python sometimes does that.

Comment: Suite: Because I know Python internally does change `a in [1,2,3]` to `a in frozenset([1,2,3])` but maybe it does this change internally each time it checks it so it might be more clever to do it manually as you purposed.

Comment: @JeromeJ no it doesn't, where did you see this?  check `dis.dis(lambda: a in [1, 2, 3])` it optimizes to a tuple but that's it. And yes you do **need** to do it manually... You are probably thinking of this: `dis.dis(lambda: a in {1, 2, 3})` on Py 3

Comment: @gnibbler What about using `frozenset` instead of `set`? The `set` doesn't need to be changed so why not?

Comment: @JeromeJ, I don't see why since we don't need it to be hashable. Why do you think it's better?

Comment: @gnibbler I thought `frozenset` would be lighter as it doesn't need the stuff required to edit it. My point was 'The simpler the better' and "Why using stuff that can do more than we need?" but maybe my intuition was wrong?

Comment: @JeromeJ, the instances are the same size. The creation and lookups take the same amount of time to run. The difference in complexity is all in the classes, so there is no extra overhead

Answer (score 4):

List Comprehension is your friend on this one:

```
ListA=['1','1','2','2','2','3','4','4','5','5','5','5']
ListB=['1','5']
ListC = [i if i not in ListB else 'x' for i in ListA]

--> ['x', 'x', '2', '2', '2', '3', '4', '4', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
```

Hope this helps!