# python list compare and replace

Tags: python, list

i have 2 lists. First list, `listA` is a list of lists.

```
listA=[[1,2,5,3],[3,1,5],[7,9,2]]
```

Second list, `listB` is a list that i am gonna compare against other lists in listA

```
listB=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

i want to compare the lists in listA individually and replace with 'T' if the list item exist in listB. If not, keep the listB item. It should be something like this

```
listC=[['T','T','T',4,'T',6,7,8,9,10],['T',2,'T',4,'T',6,7,8,9,10],[1,'T',3,4,5,6,'T',8,'T',10]]
```

I have tried something like this:

```
for item in listA:
    for i in range(10):
        listC.append([i if i not in item else 'T' for i in listB])
```

Doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What happens?

Comment: Also, where did that number 52 come from? You have three lists of up to 10 items up to the number 10, and another list of exactly 10 items up to 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555921/python-list-operation?rq=1). You asked nearly the exact same question last month

Comment: @Brian it is quit similar. But this time the list i want to compare is in a list of lists. I know the question sounds stupid but i didn't know i can nest the `list comprehensions` like DaoWen did.

Comment: @abarnert my mistake. 52 was the number i am using in my script. But for simplicity i made it 10 in this question. I forgot to change it when i copied to here.

Comment: @ChrisAung You found a good place to learn! I wish I came here sooner when I was learning python.

Comment: @abarnert doesn't seem to work because it is creating 10 copies of what i want. But DaoWen's answer was perfect .. thanks for the help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
listC = [ [ ('T' if b in a else b) for b in listB ] for a in listA ]
```

The parentheses are not necessary, but they might make it a bit more readable.

`x if cond else y` is Python's equivalent of the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

`[ f(x) for x in xs ]` produces a new list where the function `f` has been applied to every element in the collection `xs`.

Answer (score 2):

Nice and readable :)

```
listC = []
for i in listA:
    temp = []
    for x in listB:
        if x in i:
            temp.append('T')
        else:
            temp.append(x)
    listC.append(temp)

print listC
```

Prints:

```
[['T', 'T', 'T', 4, 'T', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['T', 2, 'T', 4, 'T', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'T', 3, 4, 5, 6, 'T', 8, 'T', 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @DaoWen is nice, to be more efficient you may pre-convert the list elements to `set`s:

```
>>> listA=[[1,2,5,3],[3,1,5],[7,9,2]]
>>> listB=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> setA = [set(A) for A in listA]
>>> [['T' if x in A else x for x in listB] for A in setA]
[['T', 'T', 'T', 4, 'T', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['T', 2, 'T', 4, 'T', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 'T', 3, 4, 5, 6, 'T', 8, 'T', 10]]
```

Comment: Why is using `set` more efficient than using list?

Comment: @ChrisAung Checking if something is in a set is `O(1)` amortized as opposed to `O(N)` for lists

Comment: jamylak: Of course when N is 3 or 4 a set may be _slower_ than a list, because hashing a value takes longer than a linear search of 4 elements. (Well, maybe not in this case—the values are all small ints, which are basically free to hash.) But really, the performance only matters if N is non-tiny, and in that case, sets always win big, so +1 to the answer and the explanation.